# How to extract values in between { } through regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract value between `{ }` using

```
"\\(\\{[^}]+\\}\\)"
```

regex in java. My input is

```
String text = "Hi this is {text to be extracted}."
```

I want output as

```
"text to be extracted"
```

but that regex isn't working.

Comment: You could do this with regex, but i think a simple `substring` would be enough if you only want to extract one value.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
"\\{([^}]*)\\}"
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB8kA4/1)

Then `$1` is containing `text to be extracted`.

Comment: Yes lookbehind could be fine too ... But I think my pattern is more readable ..

Comment: Just `"\\{([^}]*)\\}"` would be good

Answer (score 3):

The regexp seems malformed.
You need to match extra characters before and after the group, and you do not need to escape the parenthesis.
Also, you can use the named group to extract  exactly the text you care about

Here is working code

```
    String text = "Hi this is {text to be extracted}.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\{(?<t>[^}]+)\\}.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group("t"));
    }
```

Comment: you can use `Matcher#find()` and omit `.*`s

Comment: True, I'd forgot about that.